# select join using @NamedNativeQueries on non entity class

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I would like to retrieve data from complex join select only for reports propose. I decided to use @NamedNativeQueries in class without @Entity annotation as follows

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "detailInformationForInvoicePurpose",
                query = "SELECT DISTINCT b.ShipName, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipAddress, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipCity, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipRegion, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipPostalCode, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipCountry, \n" +
                        "    b.CustomerID, \n" +
                        "    c.CompanyName, \n" +
                        "    c.Address, \n" +
                        "    c.City, \n" +
                        "    c.Region, \n" +
                        "    c.PostalCode, \n" +
                        "    c.Country, \n" +
                        "    concat(d.FirstName,  ' ', d.LastName) AS Salesperson, \n" +
                        "    b.OrderID, \n" +
                        "    b.OrderDate, \n" +
                        "    b.RequiredDate, \n" +
                        "    b.ShippedDate, \n" +
                        "    a.CompanyName, \n" +
                        "    e.ProductID, \n" +
                        "    f.ProductName, \n" +
                        "    e.UnitPrice, \n" +
                        "    e.Quantity, \n" +
                        "    e.Discount,\n" +
                        "    e.UnitPrice * e.Quantity * (1 - e.Discount) AS ExtendedPrice,\n" +
                        "    b.Freight\n" +
                        "FROM Shippers a \n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Orders b ON a.ShipperID = b.ShipVia \n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Employees d ON d.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Order_Details e ON b.OrderID = e.OrderID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Products f ON f.ProductID = e.ProductID\n" +
                        "ORDER BY b.ShipName",
                resultClass = JpaReport.class)
})
public class JpaReport {
    private String shipname;
    private String shipaddress;
    private String shipcity;
    private String shipregion;
    private String shippostalcode;
    private String shipcountry;
    private String customerid;
    private String companyname;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String region;
    private String postalcode;
    private String country;
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private Long orderid;
    private java.sql.Timestamp orderdate;
    private java.sql.Timestamp requireddate;
    private java.sql.Timestamp shippeddate;

    public JpaReport(String shipname, String shipaddress, String shipcity, String shipregion, String shippostalcode, String shipcountry, String customerid, String companyname, String address, String city, String region, String postalcode, String country, String lastname, String firstname, Long orderid, Timestamp orderdate, Timestamp requireddate, Timestamp shippeddate) {
        this.shipname = shipname;
        this.shipaddress = shipaddress;
        this.shipcity = shipcity;
        this.shipregion = shipregion;
        this.shippostalcode = shippostalcode;
        this.shipcountry = shipcountry;
        this.customerid = customerid;
        this.companyname = companyname;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.region = region;
        this.postalcode = postalcode;
        this.country = country;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.orderid = orderid;
        this.orderdate = orderdate;
        this.requireddate = requireddate;
        this.shippeddate = shippeddate;
    }
```

When I try to retrieve data as list from JpaReport class I have information please look at screenshot

```
@Repository
public class JpaReportDaoImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<JpaReport> detailInformationForInvoicePurpose(){
        List<JpaReport> jpaReport = em.createNamedQuery("detailInformationForInvoicePurpose", JpaReport.class).getResultList();
        return jpaReport;
    }

}
```

[image]

I have a question:

- What am I doing wrong?
- This is a good way to retrieve data only for
  the report?

I try also to extract data as follows

```
 public List<JpaReport> detailInformationForInvoicePurpose(){
        List<JpaReport> jpaReport = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT b.ShipName, \n" +
                "    b.ShipAddress, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipCity, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipRegion, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipPostalCode, \n" +
                        "    b.ShipCountry, \n" +
                        "    b.CustomerID, \n" +
                        "    c.CompanyName as customersCompasnyName, \n" +
                        "    c.Address, \n" +
                        "    c.City, \n" +
                        "    c.Region, \n" +
                        "    c.PostalCode, \n" +
                        "    c.Country, \n" +
                        "    concat(d.FirstName,  ' ', d.LastName) AS Salesperson, \n" +
                        "    b.OrderID, \n" +
                        "    b.OrderDate, \n" +
                        "    b.RequiredDate, \n" +
                        "    b.ShippedDate, \n" +
                        "    a.CompanyName as shipersCompanyName, \n" +
                        "    e.ProductID, \n" +
                        "    f.ProductName, \n" +
                        "    e.UnitPrice, \n" +
                        "    e.Quantity, \n" +
                        "    e.Discount,\n" +
                        "    e.UnitPrice * e.Quantity * (1 - e.Discount) AS ExtendedPrice,\n" +
                        "    b.Freight\n" +
                        "FROM Shippers a \n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Orders b ON a.ShipperID = b.ShipVia \n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Employees d ON d.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Order_Details e ON b.OrderID = e.OrderID\n" +
                        "INNER JOIN Products f ON f.ProductID = e.ProductID\n" +
                        "ORDER BY b.ShipName").getResultList();
        return jpaReport;
    }
```

but when I want to iterate by `List<JpaReport>` as follows I get an error

```
List<JpaReport> jpaReports = jpaReportDaoImpl.detailInformationForInvoicePurpose();
        for (JpaReport jpaReport : jpaReports) {
            System.out.println(jpaReport);
        }
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ###################.model.JpaReport

Comment: The JPA spec only allows you to define named queries on an Entity class. Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus JPA) allow you to do it on any, but that is then vendor specific. Put it on an Entity class, as per the JPA spec

Comment: Please look above I updated my question

Comment: What of it? You execute a query with multiple results and are surprised that each row is object[]. That is what the jpa spec tells you! read it

Comment: If you want a custom result type, for a native query, have a look at this: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Well as it is not managed entity class, query annotation are not processed at all, resulting in missing query. Move query annotations to a managed (@Entity) class.

Comment: I moved @NamedNativeQuery do Shippers @Entity class but result is the same `@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "detailInformationForInvoicePurpose",
                query = "Query string like above",
                resultClass = JpaReport.class)
})
public class Shippers {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long shipperid;
  private String companyname;
  private String phone;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="orderid")
  private List<Orders> orders;

Comment: @jocom were you able to manage this. I have wprk on exact same problem. I have db view managed to entity and were using JPA QL on top of that. But more data is crashing this and need to move where clause inside view query and only way i can manage now is using native query. Can use old way of using statement extecutequery setParameter etc. But i prefer using JPA.